# Convert floating point to fixed point

Tags: python, fixed-point

I want to convert floating point sin values to fixed point values.

```
import numpy as np

Fs = 8000
f = 5
sample = 8000
x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
```

How can I easily convert this `y` floating point samples to fixed point samples?

Each element should be of 16bit and 1 bit integer part and 15 bits should be of fractional part, so that I can pass these samples to a DAC chip.

Comment: Multiply every y item by 2**15 to convert to Q15. With the requested representation you cannot represent the value 1.

Comment: yes you are rite, may be the highest +ve value is 0.999.... the dac input excepts the 2's complement values of Q1.15....

Comment: As mentioned by omegatre you cannot represent the value 1 with the requested fixed-point format. So I recommend to multiply every y by (2**15 - 1) to avoid a possible overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the samples from `float` to `Q1.15`, multiply the samples by `2 ** 15`. However, as mentioned in the comments, you can't represent `1.0` in `Q1.15`, since the LSB is representing the sign. Therefore you should clamp your values in the range of `[-1, MAX_Q1_15]` where `MAX_Q1_15 = 1.0 - (2 ** -15)`. This can be done with a few helpful numpy functions.

```
y_clamped = np.clip(y, -1.0, float.fromhex("0x0.fffe"))
y_fixed = np.multiply(y_clamped, 32768).astype(np.int16)
```

Although you may fear this representation does not accurately represent the value of `1.0`, it is close enough to do computation with. For example, if you were to square `1.0`:

```
fmul_16x16 = lambda x, y: x * y >> 15
fmul_16x16(32767, 32767) # Result --> 32766
```

Which is very close, with 1-bit error.

Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fxpmath](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath) to convert float values to fractional fixed-point. It supports Numpy arrays as inputs, so:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

# your example code here

y_fxp = Fxp(y, signed=True, n_word=16, n_frac=15)

# plotting code here
```

[image: eQ16.15]

15 bits for fractional give you a very low value for amplitue resolution, so I plot Q5.4 to show the conversion in an exaggerated way:

[image]