# Properly converting float64 to 16bit fixed point for PYNQ

Tags: python, casting, bit-manipulation, fpga, xilinx

I need to convert a float64 value into a fixed point <16,15> (16 bit with 15 bit in the fractional part and 1 in the integer part).

I have already read many solutions:

1. [Convert floating point to fixed point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702343/convert-floating-point-to-fixed-point)
2. [Simple Fixed-Point Conversion in C](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2018/07/12/simple-fixed-point-conversion-in-c/)
3. The [fxpmath](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath) library

However I have not really understood the "type" I need in my specific case.

To explain this better, I have implemented a code that generates a simple sine wave inside PYNQ (the Xilinx framework based on Python):

```
import numpy as np
###
fs = 44100  
n_samples = 1024 
f_sig = 130 #selected to get almost exactly a single frequency bin (43.066 * 3)
A = 1
seconds = 1

t = np.arange(0,seconds, step=1/fs)

#resolution of fft = fs/n_samples -> 44100/1024 = 43.066
data_in = A * np.sin(2*np.pi*f_sig*t)
data_in = data_in[:1024]
###
```

Which generates a simple sine wave and then I select the first 1024 samples. The goal of this selection is to send those samples to a FFT logicore block ([FFT logicore documentation](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/xfft/v9_1/pg109-xfft.pdf#page=16)). In my specific case, the FFT has been configured to accept 16 bit fixed point inputs <16,15> for real and imaginary part (you can find more info in the documentation at page 18) and perform a 1024 points FFT. So basically I need to convert this sinusoid from `float64` to `ap_fixed<16,15>`

However, I am not sure of which Python datatype I should use in my conversion. For example, in the second approach, it uses a `uint16` to store the data after conversion. In the third approach the library returns an object.

When calling the function to copy the input to the DMA buffer and compute the FFT I have the following code:

```
from pynq imort Overlay
from pynq import allocate

dma = overlay.axi_dma_0
buff_in = allocate(1024, 'uknown type') # which type should I use here? 
buff_in[:] = data_in[:]
np.copyto(buff_in, data_in, casting="unsafe")
dma.sendchannel.transfer(buff_in)
```

I understood the basic algorithm which should be something like:

```
import numpy as np
my_casting_int = int32(np.round(data_in * 2**15)))
my_casting_uint = uint32(np.round(data_in * 2**15)))
```

But again, I don't know if I need a signed or unsigned casting, considering that the input data is a `float64` sinusoid with sign.

To sum everything up:

1. My FFT expects 2 arrays of `ap_fixed<16,15>` for each input sample, one for the real part and one for the imaginary part. Being a real input sample, I will have 16 bits with the real part and 16 bits which are basically all zeros for the imaginary part.
2. I need to convert my sinusoid from Python `float64` into a suitable format for my FFT core (which is `ap_fixed<16,15>`).
3. I don't know which Python type I should use after the casting from `float64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that FFT expects ap_fixed<16,15>, where MSB is the sign bit. In your example you have signed samples (because sinusoidal between -1.0 and 1.0), so your casting must be `int` (signed int). But if you need a two-complement representation of signed int, it's right if you cast with `uint`. In both cases, cast with 16 bits is enough.

```py
np.round(data_in*2**15).astype(np.int16) # returns -16384
np.round(data_in*2**15).astype(np.uint16) # returns 49152
```

If you use `float64` and need to translate to ap_fixed<16,15> (`fxp-s16/15` or `S1.15` type) take care about rounding and truncation methods.

If you use **fxpmath**, it's more clear what conversion you are doing. It's true that an object is returned, but you can extract the `int` (raw) value by `raw` method, or `uint` by `uraw` method:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

#...

data_in_fxp = Fxp(data_in, dtype='fxp-s16/15') # or dtype='S1.15'

raw_data_int = data_in_fxp.raw()
raw_data_uint = data_in_fxp.uraw() # two-complement
```

A numpy array is returned by those method. If you need a python `list` of `int`, just use `tolist` method, for example: `data_in_fxp.raw().tolist()`

Rounding and overflow behaviors could be modified, for more info visit [fxpmath#behaviors](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath#behaviors)

Comment: This was very helpful, I wrote the code and it works perfectly. However, do you know how I can go back to my fractional representation after I extracted my uraw? 
As an example, I am using a variable like ```n = Fxp(-0.5, signed=True, n_word=20, n_frac=16)``` which uraw returns  ```1015808 ``` . Do you know how I can go back to the original -0.5 value?

Comment: `Fxp` doesn't have (yet) a method to load _uraw_, only _raw_. A workaround can be load the value into a `Fxp` with a **wrap overflow** to deal with two-complement. In this case you can use `Fxp(1015808, like=data_in_fxp, raw=True, overflow='wrap')` or `Fxp(1015808, signed=True, n_word=20, n_frac=16, raw=True, overflow='wrap')`.

Comment: In the end I wrote my own custom wrapper for "forward" and "backward" conversion. Yu can find it here (with also a tutorial): https://github.com/mattiasu96/PYNQ-ap_fixed-converter.
I hope this might be helpful for future developers.